# Parse de String separada por valores nulos

Tags: c++, winapi

Eu estou usando o `OpenFileName` da winapi com a flag de multiselect.
Quando o usuario seleciona varios arquivos ele me retorna uma string separada por nulos conforme o modelo a seguir:

```
"[caminho da pasta]\0[arquivo 1]\0[arquivo 2]\0[arquivo 3]\0\0"
```

Como eu poderia transformar essa string em um array? Existe algum metodo do proprio c++ para isso? Caso não, como eu posso fazer para identificar o `"\0"` em for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma string em C é uma sequencia de caracteres finalizadas por um terminador nulo. Então dado que você tenha:

```
const char* data = "[caminho da pasta]\0[arquivo 1]\0[arquivo 2]\0[arquivo 3]\0\0";
```

Você pode calcular o tamanho da primeira string usando o `strlen`:

```
const char* str1 = data;
int len1 = strlen(str1);
```

A segunda string vai começar depois da primeira e depois do terminador nulo, assim:

```
const char* str2 = str1 + len1 + 1;
int len2 = strlen(str2);
```

E assim sucessivamente. Você pára quando o `len` retornar zero, afinal o fim é marcado por um duplo marcador nulo.

Você pode fazer em um loop assim:

```
int main() {
    const char* data = "[caminho da pasta]\0[arquivo 1]\0[arquivo 2]\0[arquivo 3]\0\0";

    vector<string> files;

    const char* str = data;
    int len = strlen(str);

    while (len) {
        files.push_back(string(str, len));
        str = str + len + 1;
        len = strlen(str);
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "[" << i << "] = '" << files[i] << "'" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Resultando em:

```
[0] = '[caminho da pasta]'
[1] = '[arquivo 1]'
[2] = '[arquivo 2]'
[3] = '[arquivo 3]'
```

[Exemplo funcional (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2796db77a394c29)

Comment: e esse tipo de loop funcionaria para uma string de tipo wchar_t?

Comment: @RaphaelRosa Sim, basta usar `wcslen` no lugar de `strlen`.

Comment: legal... valeu mesmo cara